# beforerender method does not working on jsreport studio in local machine

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js, jsreport

I used following code but script code beforerender method is does't working in local machine.can some tell me y this method not working.

html code using handlebars on jsreport studio:

```
<table>
    <tr>
    <th>Country</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>abbrivation</th>
    <th>Area</th>
    <th>Largest_city</th>
    <th>capital</th>
    </tr>
   {{#each stats.RestResponse.result}}
   <tr>
       <td>{{country}}</td>
       <td>{{name}}</td>
       <td>{{abbr}}</td>
       <td>{{area}}</td>
       <td>{{largest_city}}</td>
       <td>{{capital}}</td>
   </tr>
   {{/each}}
</table>


Script code:

function beforeRender(done) { 
    require('request')({  url:"http://services.groupkt.com/state/get/IND/all",   json:true}, function(err, response, body){
        console.log("check-->",JSON.stringify(body));
        request.template.content = JSON.stringify(body);
        request.data = { stats: body };
        done();
    });

}
```

Comment: Not sure to understand ... did you forget some code or is everything present ? Where is your handlebar code ?  Also if you want to use a handlebar template you should add the declaration with the script tag.

Comment: This is jsreport studio installed in local machine. i got output same code run through online for jsreport studio, In jsreport studio the script ajax response is print on html using handlebar i.e {{#each stats.RestResponse.result}} which end with {{/each}}. That is exact code (if  u know jsreport studio ?)

Comment: Ok I didn't know this tool. Is the online version working with the exact same code or it has problems to be run also ?

Comment: Thanks, In online there is no problem all working fine. i had problem in after setup jsreport studio in local machine.

Comment: You're welcome I'm glad you've found your answer

Comment: No now looking what's the problem the beforerender() method does't run while run jsreport studio.

Answer (score 0):

Here i missed the configuration for jsrport studio local. I find answer here 
https://jsreport.net/blog/introducing-jsreport-cli